# How to fix the footer in bottom of last page?

Tags: css, jsreport

[image]In Jsreport am having 5 to 6 pages of content. I am having the footer also. So i want to set the footer in bottom of last page. Please anyone suggest.

Comment: How does your current code look like? :)

Comment: Currently in every page bottom the footer is showing. I used the css for footer is footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:10px;
}

Comment: can u give screenshot?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: <footer style="  position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:10px;border:1px solid red;">
   <h1>This is my footer</h1>
</footer>

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Let me know if this helpful.

```
<footer style=" position:fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; right:0px;border:1px solid red;">
 <h1>This is my footer</h1>
</footer>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can't solve this with just css, because fixed or absolute positioning of the element will make the footer visible on every page and you want to have it just on the last one.

However I believe you can solve it with jsreport [pdf-utils extension](https://jsreport.net/learn/pdf-utils). The trick looks like this.

Define an extra template representing the footer. Use the css to put the content to the bottom. And use custom handlebars helper to display the footer only for the last page.

```
{{#lastPage}}
<style>
    .footer {
        position: fixed; 
        bottom: 0; 
        width: 100%; 
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
<div class='footer'>
    content
</div>
{{/lastPage}}

// custom helper
function lastPage(opts) {      
  if (this.$pdf.pageIndex === (this.$pdf.pages.length - 1)) {
    return opts.fn(this)
  }

  return ''
}
```

Then append to the main content an empty placeholder which will reserve the space for the footer.

```
<!--placeholder for the footer-->
<div style='height:50px;'></div>
```

The last step is to configure pdf utils extension to merge the footer template with "render for every page" selected.

I prepared demo in the jsreport playground so you can fiddle with it.
https://playground.jsreport.net/w/anon/~~Cb62wD